# How to unpack a binary file buffer into two variables?

Tags: python, unpack

I have a binary file that contains 4-byte binary values that represent a set of two `short int` each. I know that I can unpack a single 4-byte binary value into two short integers like this:

```
from struct import unpack

fval = b'\xba\x1e\x99\x01' #actualy read from some file
qualdip, azi = unpack('hh', fval)
print(type(qualdip), qualdip)
print(type(azi), azi)

>>> <class 'int'> 7866
>>> <class 'int'> 409
```

Now, I want to unpack the entire buffer. For the moment I am doing:

```
qualdips = []
azis = []
with open(bfile, 'rb') as buf:
    fval = buf.read(4)
    while fval:
        qualdip, azi = unpack('hh', fval)
        azis.append(azi)
        qualdips.append(qualdip)
        fval = buf.read(4)
```

Which takes over a minute for a 277MB file and seems to produce a huge memory overhead.

I would like to unpack the entire filebuffer directly into the two variables. How do I accomplish this?

I suspect that [`struct.unpack_from`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) is my friend, but I am unsure how to formulate the format.

```
with open(bfile, 'rb') as buf:
    qualdip, azi = unpack_from('hh', buf)
```

only extracts two values, and (i know the number of elements of my file)

```
with open(bfile, 'rb') as buf:
    qualdip, azi = unpack_from('72457091h72457091h', buf)
```

expects this ridiculous amount of output variables. So:

How *do* I unpack the entire filebuffer directly into the two variables?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where the overhead is? If the i/o operations are taking the longest time, you might try reading from the file in larger blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to unpack the values directly into two lists, but you can unpack the entire file into a tuple and then slice it in two:

```
fval = b'\xba\x1e\x99\x01' * 3
unpacked= unpack('3h3h', fval)
qualdip = unpacked[0::2]
azi = unpacked[1::2]
```

Alternatively, use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to create an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), which will reduce memory consumption.

```
qualdip = islice(unpacked, 0, None, 2)
azi = islice(unpacked, 1, None, 2)
```

Comment: islice only returns the iterator object, but I need the actual values. Slicing works great. I now use `qualdip = unpacked[0::2]`, `azi = unpacked[1::2]`.

Comment: I edited your answer accordingly, however, I am unsure about how to get the actual values from the islice object generated in the second block of the answer.

Comment: @wsj `islice` is a [generator object](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/292/generators-yield#t=201607221128531431962), you can iterate over it with `for value in azi:` or get the values one by one with `next(azi)`.

Comment: Thanks, I need all the values in the grid at once in order to plot them. So the slicing part is the answer I have looked for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a faster way to do it:

```
import os
import struct

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

bfile = 'bfile.bin'
filesize = os.stat(bfile).st_size
numvals = filesize // 2

with open(bfile, 'rb') as bf:
    fmt = '{}h'.format(numvals)
    values = struct.unpack(fmt, str(bf.read()))

qualdips, azis = zip(*pairwise(values))
```